# Google assistant in other country - pause music

Tags: google-home, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

I live in Poland, where Google Assistant isn't allowed (operated) and I would like to write a simple script, which allow me to say: "Ok, google, muzyka stop". Next device will stop music play. Is it possible to write this in dialogflow or other system?

Answer (score 0):

When creating apps for the Google Assistant I'd recommend staying away from use cases already covered by the Google Assistant. In this case controlling music is already covered by the Google Assistant and will already work with most music streaming providers.

If you'd like to add the Google Assistant to your device and add the option to control your device, a conversational building tool like Dialogflow is probably not the best tool.  You may want to consider adding the Google Assistant and voice controls to you device use the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/).